# Js Array detect: number of values from php array found (grabbed from database)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, ajax

This is (again) about array (in my Google map project). After being voteddown, finally I succeed to show multiple markers based on Db data.

I have two PHP pages:

```
 1. inc.php
 2. index.php
```

In **inc.php** contains values in *php array*, as follow:

```
    //...... previous code
    $googlemap=$result['googlemap'];
    $map[] = $googlemap;
    } 
echo implode(', ' , $map);
```

The result shows: `-5.364000343425874,-150.364000343425874-5.362878747789552,-150.3640003436345874` (this line contains 2 values for example)

To get the values, I use native Ajax:

In **index.php** contains Javascript codes to fetch the php array (`inc.php`), *extract* them into each values for latt and long value, as follow:

1. Array Values from inc.php is caught by this code:

`var wwwsitus = document.querySelector("#valdata").value;`

The value inside `#valdata` grabbed by native ajax:

```
<script>
function strQuery(str) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("valdata").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
            script_dkill()
            }
        }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "inc.php?q="+str, true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
    //start: calling maps
    function script_dkill() {
    // --- some codes ---
    //..........
    //}
</script>
```

2. Extract `#valdata`:

`var n_result = wwwsitus.split(',');
var x0 = n_result[0];
var y0 = n_result[1];
var x1 = n_result[2];
var y1 = n_result[3];`

3. Show the map from this format array:

`var wwwsitus = [
  ['<h4>Universitas Lampung</h4>', x0,y0],
  ['<h4>Universitas Lampung</h4>', x1,y1]
];`

All works 100%.
**The problem is**:
Values grabbed from database can be 1, 2 or more. (here, I limit the values into 5).

**Question**:
How do I detect the values in `#valdata` if `#valdata` contains 1 or more values so that I can create `if` for the result???. or, you have other suggestion to handle this.

I hope my question is very clear and pls help me out from this. Thnks.

**UPDATED:**
What I expect is, for instance:

```
var wwwsitus = document.querySelector("#valdata").value;
var n_result = wwwsitus.split(','); 
    if (wwwsitus =null) {
       alert('No rent-house found near the place'); // if no value.
       // no action
        }
    else if (wwwsitus =1) {
        alert('Found 1 rent-houses'); // if found only 1 value
//continue to show the map based on the value - will show 1 marker.
        var x0 = n_result[0];
        var y0 = n_result[1];
        var wwwsitus = [['<h4>Kost 1</h4>', x0,y0]];
        }
    else if (wwwsitus =2) {
        alert('Found 2 rent-houses'); //if found 2 value
// continue to show the value - will show 2 markers.
        var x0 = n_result[0];
        var y0 = n_result[1];
        var x1 = n_result[2];
        var y1 = n_result[3];
        var wwwsitus = [['<h4>Kost 1</h4>', x0,y0],['<h4>Kost 2</h4>', x1,y1]];
    }
```

HOWEVER, the `alert()` NOT SHOWING the real number of the values as in the Database. How should I code with this.?

Comment: If you need full codes, I will update it with it.

Comment: Would a loop work instead? `wwwsitus=wwwsitus.split(','); for (var i = 0; i < wwwsitus.length - 1; i += 2) { x = wwwsitus[i]; y = wwwsitus[i+1]; }`

Comment: Unfortunately no, because var `x` and `y` must be unique for each values. I've ever tried with the loop and map markers become one place (the two values above is different places in one area). See demo here: http://www.wwwsitus.com/lab/id/. keyword: "universitas lampung" . My code works and fine. I need to know how to detect the number of values inside `#valdata` by using common `if`.

Comment: `var pairCount = wwwsitus.split(',') / 2;`?

Comment: Hi @JohnSteel, like I mentioned above, my code is okay. Yeah, perhaps, I'm stupid of coding method :D but it works. okay, I'll update my question in a minute

Comment: Pls see my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following solution perhaps stupid coding. But it finally works 1000%.

To detect number of values inside `#valdata`, I add one input field as follow:

1. `<input type='hidden' id='numvalue' value=''/>`
2. Create native Ajax again to grabbed the information about number of values in new file (e.g. `num_inc.php`)

Here, with that ajax, I will be able to get number of values exist based on mysql query and send to input field `#numvalue`.

Here's in `num_inc.php` last code:

```
$result = $uQuery->fetchColumn(); 
if($result> 0) {
    echo $result; // number of value detected!!!
    }
```

From the process, I finally can extract the data from `#valdata` and display the map successfully.

Here's the full code:

```
        <script>
            //document.getElementById("qfront").addEventListener("keydown", CalmDown, false);
            function script_grabbed(str) {
              var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                  document.getElementById("numvalue").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
                  var datafound = document.getElementById("numvalue").value;
                    var xmlhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
                      if (xmlhttp2.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp2.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("valdata").value = xmlhttp2.responseText;
                        var wwwsitus = document.getElementById("valdata").value;
                        var n_result = wwwsitus.split(',');
                            if (datafound == 1) {
                                var x0 = n_result[0];
                                var y0 = n_result[1];
                                var wwwsitus = [
                                    ['<h4></h4>', x0,y0]
                                    ];
                                }
                            else if (datafound == 2) {
                                var x0 = n_result[0];
                                var y0 = n_result[1];
                                var x1 = n_result[2];
                                var y1 = n_result[3];
                                var wwwsitus = [
                                    ['<h4></h4>', x0,y0],
                                    ['<h4></h4>', x1,y1]
                                    ];
                                }   
                            else if (datafound == 3) {
                                var x0 = n_result[0];
                                var y0 = n_result[1];
                                var x1 = n_result[2];
                                var y1 = n_result[3];
                                var x2 = n_result[4];
                                var y2 = n_result[5];
                                var wwwsitus = [
                                    ['<h4></h4>', x0,y0],
                                    ['<h4></h4>', x1,y1],
                                    ['<h4></h4>', x2,y2]
                                    ];
                                }   
                            else if (datafound == 4) {
                                var x0 = n_result[0];
                                var y0 = n_result[1];
                                var x1 = n_result[2];
                                var y1 = n_result[3];
                                var x2 = n_result[4];
                                var y2 = n_result[5];
                                var x3 = n_result[6];
                                var y3 = n_result[7];
                                var wwwsitus = [
                                    ['<h4></h4>', x0,y0],
                                    ['<h4></h4>', x1,y1],
                                    ['<h4></h4>', x2,y2],
                                    ['<h4></h4>', x3,y3]
                                    ];
                                }   
                            else if (datafound == 5) {
                                var x0 = n_result[0];
                                var y0 = n_result[1];
                                var x1 = n_result[2];
                                var y1 = n_result[3];
                                var x2 = n_result[4];
                                var y2 = n_result[5];
                                var x3 = n_result[6];
                                var y3 = n_result[7];
                                var x4 = n_result[8];
                                var y4 = n_result[9];
                                var wwwsitus = [
                                    ['<h4></h4>', x0,y0],
                                    ['<h4></h4>', x1,y1],
                                    ['<h4></h4>', x2,y2],
                                    ['<h4></h4>', x3,y3],
                                    ['<h4></h4>', x4,y4]
                                    ];
                                }   
                            else{
                                var no_kampus = document.querySelector("#qfront").value;
                                alert('Data Kost Sekitar Kampus ' + '"'+no_kampus+'"' + ' Belum Terdaftar!');
                                }       
                        // Setup the different icons and shadows
                        var iconURLPrefix = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';

                        var icons = [
                          iconURLPrefix + 'red-dot.png',
                          iconURLPrefix + 'green-dot.png',
                          iconURLPrefix + 'blue-dot.png',
                          iconURLPrefix + 'orange-dot.png',
                          iconURLPrefix + 'purple-dot.png',
                          iconURLPrefix + 'pink-dot.png',      
                          iconURLPrefix + 'yellow-dot.png'
                        ]
                        var iconsLength = icons.length;

                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                          zoom: 10,
                          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.92, 151.25),
                          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                          mapTypeControl: true,
                          streetViewControl: true,
                          panControl: true,
                          zoomControlOptions: {
                             position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
                          }
                        });

                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                          maxWidth: 160
                        });

                        var markers = new Array();

                        var iconCounter = 0;

                        // Add the markers and infowindows to the map
                        for (var i = 0; i < wwwsitus.length; i++) {  
                          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(wwwsitus[i][1], wwwsitus[i][2]),
                            map: map,
                            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                            icon: icons[iconCounter]
                          });

                          markers.push(marker);

                          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                            return function() {
                              infowindow.setContent(wwwsitus[i][0]);
                              infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            }
                          })(marker, i));

                          iconCounter++;
                          // We only have a limited number of possible icon colors, so we may have to restart the counter
                          if(iconCounter >= iconsLength) {
                            iconCounter = 0;
                          }
                        }

                        function autoCenter() {
                          //  Create a new viewpoint bound
                          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                          //  Go through each...
                          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
                                    bounds.extend(markers[i].position);
                          }
                          //  Fit these bounds to the map
                          map.fitBounds(bounds);
                        }
                        autoCenter();


                      }
                    }
                    xmlhttp2.open("POST", "inc.php?q=" + str, true);
                    xmlhttp2.send(null);
                }
              }
              xmlhttp.open("POST", "inc_num.php?q=" + str, true);
              xmlhttp.send(null);
            }
    </script>
```

**Input Field:**

```
<input id="qfront" name="qfront" placeholder="Type your campus ..." 
value="" type="text" onKeyPress="script_grabbed(this.value);"  />
<input id="valdata" name="valdata" type="hidden" value=""/>
<input id="numvalue" name="numvalue" type="hidden" value=""/>
```

in **num_inc.php:**

```
$result = $uQuery->fetchColumn(); 
if($result> 0) {
    echo $result;
    }
```

in **inc.php:**

```
    $googlemap=$result['googlemap'];
    $map[] = $googlemap;
    } 
echo implode(', ' , $map);
```

**NOTE:** If you have another nice solution, please let me know. Of course, I like the better one than I attempt.

Complete Source: [Github](https://github.com/nzcage/googlemap/blob/master/Multiple%20Markers%20-%20Database%20Version)